# React router change url without page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I was using react-router 0.13.3, it was ok: i was changing url and transition without reload was happening.

Now, in react-router 2.0 if I'm changing url manually, my app gets reloaded entirely instead of simple redirect.
How do i fix it?

I want to use this:

```
<a href="/routename">link</a>
```

instead this:

```
<Link to="/routename">link</Link>
```

In few special cases.

#### Routes

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router";
import App from './components/App';
import FrontPage from './components/frontPage/FrontPage';
import User from './components/user/User';
module.exports = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={FrontPage}/>
            <Route path="/user/:userid" component={User}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: code? Need to see what you are doing so we can help

Comment: @JohnRuddell i've added code, please take a look

Comment: why would you want to use <a> instead of <Link>? <Link> turns into an <a> after being compiled.

Comment: i use css-framework, which utilizes inlined html code. I can't use `<Link>` there, because it will not be compiled into `<a>`

Comment: I think that you should post your routes.js

Comment: @QoP added to description

Comment: @stkvtflw react router uses link to do history updates and not reload the page. You can pass through any html code and that will be spread on the anchor tag when it gets compiled. Link passes any additional props down to the anchor tag via `{...props}`

Comment: I ensure you, `<Link>` will not be compiled in my case

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution. We can either `onClick` script or `Link`.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3411

Comment: It would be nice with an example.

Answer (score 3):

**React Router v4 - Redirect Component**

The react-router v4 recommended way is to allow your render method to catch a redirect. Use state or props to determine if the redirect component needs to be shown.

1. First, import the `Redirect` from `react-router`

   ```
   import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
   ```
2. Define the Click handler

   ```
   handleOnClick = () => {
       // some action...
       // then redirect
       this.setState({redirect: true});
   }
   ```
3. Change Render method like,

   ```
   render() {
       if (this.state.redirect) {
       return <Redirect push to="/yourpath" />;
       }

       return ( <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} type="button">Button</button> );
   }
   ```

   - Example code :

     ```
     import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

     export default class ConfirmationDialog extends Component{
         constructor(props)
         {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                 redirect : false
             }
         }

         handleOnClick = () => {
             // some action...
             // then redirect
             this.setState({redirect: true});
         }

         render() {
              if (this.state.redirect) {
                   return <Redirect push to="/yourpath" />;
              }

               return (
                       //your code
                       <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} 
                              type="button">Button</button>
               );

         }
     }
     ```

Reference : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's due to some error, run the web on chrome with DevTools (Shift+CTRL+I). In Console enable Preserve log (keeping logs) and see what is going you may see some error, solve it and it should work without refresh.

Answer (score -1):

**React Router v6**

The navigate method has `replace` option.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(PATHNAME, { replace: true });
```

Required import:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: This is not the use for which `replace: true` is designed.
It doesn't prevent the page from reloading, it just doesn't add steps in the browsing history, replacing the current url without adding it.

Comment: so is there a solution?