# How to push route without reload in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-router-v4, antd

I was trying to perform transition on tab click but I don't want the full app to reload. I am using ant design tabs

Here is my code snippet

```
<Tabs activeKey={activeKey} onChange={props.onTabChange}>
  {tabs.map(tab => <TabPane tab={tab.name} key={tab.key} />)}
</Tabs>
```

onChange callback

```
onTabChange = activeKey => {
  const url = `/${activekey}`;
  history.push(url);
  ...
};
```

But this leads to full app reload which I don't want. I have tried Link but no success. I have look through [React router change url without page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854642/react-router-change-url-without-page-reload) but not getting clarity also the issue link is 2 years ago might be some way around.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using `windows.history` (the global browser `history` variable). This **will** cause a reload.

You should use `this.props.history`.